# Applying a continuous function to a function with a discontinuity: Will the composition still have a discontinuity?

Tags: continuity

Let $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.
Suppose $f$ has a discontinuity at $a \in \mathbb R$.
Now suppose also a *continuous* function $g \colon  \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is given.

Is it true, then,
that the function $g \circ f  \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$
has a discontinuity in $a$ as well?

Of course, this isn't true in general, since for instance $g$ could be a constant function, and then $g \circ f$ is obviously continuous in all points, so in particular in $a$.
But, are there conditions we can give such that the statement would become true? E.g., perhaps we can assume that $g$ is non-constant in some neighborhood of $f(a)$, and this would suffice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $g$ is the identity function, what happens?

Comment: I am not optimistic that you are going to come up with any particularly nice characterization, as there are all kinds of pathologies which might get smoothed out by a sufficiently compatible function.  For example, take $f = \chi_{\mathbb{Q}} - \frac{1}{2}$ and $g = |\cdot |$.  $f$ is *highly* discontinuous, but the composition with $g$ is the constant function $1/2$.

Comment: A simple class of counterexamples: If $f$ has a jump discontinuity and jumps from $y_1$ to $y_2$ at $a$, but $g(y_1)=g(y_2)$, then $g\circ f$ will be continuous at $a$.

Comment: I'm too tired to check the details, but my intuition tells me that if $f$ has an oscillatory discontinuity at $a$ and $g$ is continuous, then $g\circ f$ is continuous if and only if $g$ is constant on some sufficiently large interval around $f(a)$ (an interval large enough to capture the entire oscillation).

Comment: @XanderHenderson. Your intuition is correct.

Comment: A jump discontinuity at $x= a$  is suppressed by   $ x \ \to \ const. +  g(x-a)$, s.t.   $g(0)=0$

Comment: @XanderHenderson Nice 'counterexample'. Thanks. I think you meant that the composition is the constant function 1/2, but I'm sure it was a typo (and it doesn't make a difference for the argument anyways).

Comment: @herbhofsterd I don't know what you are talking about. :P  (Typo corrected.)